# Blocking get aio_pika

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, pika

I expected

```
await queue.get()
```

to be blocking in aio_pika, but even when I don't set the timeout parameter I instantly get an error:

> aio_pika.exceptions.QueueEmpty

Anyway to get a blocking get in aio_pika?

EDIT:
This is the best I could come up with so far.

```
   while True:
        msg = await q.get(fail=False)
        if msg:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm getting a `QueueEmpty` even with a timeout set. Is that a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a very long timeout, according to the [documentation for that method](https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika/blob/347220c0236f845d07f255cc195458f4f50e2898/aio_pika/queue.py#L232-L244). There does not appear to be another way to do it.

Comment: The first paragraph is superfluous: StackOverflow questions are by default directed at the StackOverflow community of answerers, not at the development team of a particular product. The given information may be useful, but it belongs in a comment to the question.

Comment: Setting a long timeout seems like a sure way to get error's since there is no way to guarantee success.

Comment: Then use a short timeout, check the response, and act appropriately.

Comment: @user4815162342 - my goal as a member of the RabbitMQ core team is to let SO users know that this site is not the primary means of community support for RabbitMQ - the mailing list is.

Comment: As I said, there is no problem with that, but that kind of thing belongs in a comment.